# Timeseries : date time averaging and abnormally detection

Tags: dataframe, time-series

I"m dealing with a dataset with 4 week sales data (data will be refreshed every hour) and need to observer for abnormality
I think I'll go with a basic approach, to compare with average numbers and I'm trying to figure out how to best break this down so I can answer some questions below

- On average, how many orders received at 9:00 , 15:00 or 16:00 past 30 days
- On average, how many orders received at 9:00 every Wednesday (past 4 Wednesdays), at 15:00 every Thursday (past 4 Thursdays),
  Not sure how do we go about this (after breaking date/time down to Hour and Weekday columns)

| date | order ID | order hour | order weekday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/07/2022 10:26:12 PM | 1111 | 22 | 6 |
| 10/07/2022 10:27:12 PM | 2222 | 22 | 6 |
| .... | .... | .... | .... |
| 19/07/2022 11:34:19 AM | 9998 | 11 | 1 |
| 19/07/2022 11:34:35 AM | 9999 | 11 | 1 |

I would love to get your advice please
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up going with a tedious approach.

```
#get current hour & weekday
now=datetime.datetime.now()
today=datetime.date.today()
current_hour=now.hour
current_weekday=today.weekday()

#create a DF with orders from the same hour & weekday window
same_hour_weekday_df=order_df[(order_df.order_hour==current_hour ) & (order_df.order_weekday==current_weekday)  ]

#calculate avg orders generated from the past weeks within the same hour and weekyday timeframe
orders_same_hour_weekday=same_hour_weekday_df['order_created_at'].count()
same_hour_weekday_periods=same_hour_weekday_df['order_week'].nunique()
avg_orders_same_hour_weekday=orders_same_hour_weekday/same_hour_weekday_periods
```